# Echo contents of file into email subject

Tags: linux, bash, echo

Morning all

Hopefully a simple syntax issue - I've written a script whereas I need to echo the contents of a file which half works. The error I get is it only echo's the first word of the file and tries to send a email the other words in the file

i.e.

Contents of file: The cat sat on the mat
Email subject would be "The" and the email sent to would be cat,sat,on,the,mat,user@example.com

```
USER_HOME=$(eval echo ~${SUDO_USER})
CASEFILE="/home/user/text.txt"
rm $USER_HOME/text.txt
echo \

echo "Please enter some text"

echo \

read -p "Enter text: " CASE

echo $CASE > $USER_HOME/case.txt
OUT=$(awk '{ print $0 }' $CASEFILE)


echo "$OUT"


echo "testing" | mail -s $OUT user@example.com
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd try to add double quotes to `$OUT`:

```
echo "testing" | mail -s "$OUT" user@example.com
```